# 32-bit ARM Stack: Why the least significant 2 bits of SP must always be 0?

Tags: arm, stack

I am new to stack and try to master it, and this statement of Stack Pointer has been bugging me for hours:

"On the ARM Cortex-M processor, the stack always operates on 32-bit data. All stack accesses are word aligned, which means the least significant two bits of SP(Stack Pointer) must always be 0."

I know Stack is just a part of RAM, which contains 32-bit data, so all the operation such as PUSH/POP would need to be 32-bit operations. There are 2 questions about that statement concern me:

1. All stack accesses are "word" aligned. Should it be DWORD instead of WORD to make up for the 32 bits? If not, why Word or 16 bits rather than 32 bits for all stack accesses?
2. Why does it mean the least significant two bits of SP must always be zero?

Any thought?

Comment: a word is 32-bit in most 32-bit architectures. x86 is an exception because it was a 16-bit architecture at first so "word" in x86 means 16 bits

Answer (score 2):

*1) All stack accesses are "word" aligned. Should it be DWORD instead of WORD to make up for the 32 bits? If not, why Word or 16 bits rather than 32 bits for all stack accesses?*

The size of a word depends on the CPU architecture. On a 32 bits Cortex-M, a word is made of 32 bits, or 4 bytes.
*2) Why does it mean the least significant two bits of SP must always be zero?*
This is a different way to say that the stack should always be aligned on a 4 bytes boundary, or that the stack pointer should always contain an address which is a multiple of four bytes.

For example, binary address 0000 is 0 decimal. The three next addresses, 0001 (1 decimal), 0010, (2 decimal) and 0011 (3 decimal) binary addresses have their least significant bits set to 01, 10, and 11. 0100 (4 decimal) is the first address following 0000 with its two least significant bits set to 0:  this is the same thing than saying it is a multiple of 4 bytes, or if you prefer, a multiple of the CPU word size in bytes.

Comment: Hi Frant, thanks for the explanation, I am bit enlighted now.

Comment: Hi Frant, thanks for the explanation, I am bit enlighted now, though I am still confused on your answer of question#2. SP is a 32-bit pointer, so it contains an address of a multiple of 4 bytes. By your explanation, it seems each SP will cover 4 addresses in stack? such as SP will cover 0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000002 0x00000003? but if that the case, how can SP access to the 0x00000001 location if I want to?

Comment: My understanding is that the stack can only be accessed  by reading/writing entire words. Basically, you will push/pop full 32 bits registers. Now, if you want to read a specific byte using an address stored in a register (but not SP), see the LDRSB example here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABIAJHJ.html You will read in this paragraph  that SP can be used only when reading/writing entire words, that is in an LDR instruction, but not an LDRB or LDRH one.

Comment: the arm convention I believe desires a 64 bit aligned stack btw, the instruction set pushs and pops which are really stm and ldm instructions if you look at the encoding and thus have to be (32 bit) aligned.

Comment: There is no reason why you cant mov the stack pointer to some other register then do an strb/ldrb on local variables on the stack.  a stack frame pointer basically.

Comment: Try compiling and disassembling some simple functions to see how a compiler implements such things.

Comment: @old_timer My understanding is that the 64 bits aligned stack is more an ABI-related constraint than an architectural-related one, that is not respecting it would not cause an hardware  fault, what do you think?

Comment: @Frant - in the older architectures some of the instructions required 8 bytes alignment. So the stack on the exception entry may be automatically aligned to 8 bytes.

Comment: @old_timer modern 32bit (Mx, Axx ....)cores do not have any instructions which require 64 bits alignment.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 it is an ABI related requirement for performance it is not a silicon requirement.  Moreso for the full sized cores (32 or 64 bit), as they tend to have 64 bit busses.  I think the compilers conform to that for the cortex-ms as well though, very easy to test.

Comment: From just about the beginning of ARM (not necessarily Acorn) to the present you can disable the alignment fault.  Unaligned on the ARM7 was a rotation, the current cores will cross over as desired (x86 style), you just get the performance hit as you would expect.  Should be easy to see if the cortex-m's have this feature, I would assume but would have to double check.  Easier for performance reasons as well as clean code as well as avoiding faults to just not do unaligned transfers, so I generally dont have to mess with the enables and have to look them up.

Comment: Not counting downloading the manuals took roughly 15-20 seconds per architecture to determine the alignment fault features or lack of for the related cores.  The OP didnt specify which cortex-m